# Devise inherited controller calling the default registration form instead of the custom scoped one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise gem to create models of Clinics and Doctors who can register and sign up. In order to have separate views for each of them, I activated the following line in config/initializers/devise.rb

`config.scoped_views = true`

After generating separate views, I was able to modify the sign_up form for `Doctors` in app/views/doctors/registration/new.html.erb, and the modified form was being displayed

After this I needed to allow a signed in Doctor to create another Doctor, so I overwrote the default Devise RegistrationController as follows

```
class RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
end
```

In routes.rb, I instructed it to use this controller

```
devise_for :doctors, :controllers => {:registrations => "registration"}
```

Everything is working OK, a signed in doctor can access the registration form for creating a new doctor, except that the Form is the Devise default one for registrations, not the one I had modified in `app/views/doctors/registration/new.html.erb`

I cannot find a way to instruct my Inherited Controller to use the modified form instead of the default one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is only guess, but have you tried:

    devise_for :doctors, :controllers => {:registrations => "doctors/registration"}

Comment: Yes, I tried this and also changed the class declaration as follows
`class Doctors::RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController` but it does not change anything unfortunately

Comment: checkout https://github.com/plataformatec/devise anchor "Configuring views" if you didn't already.